# RCTDevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true) errors out with "undefined is not an object"

Tags: ios, react-native

Using react native version 0.43.3, I am trying to enable the debug remotely option using the RCTDevSettings.

```
import {
   NativeModules
} from 'react-native'
```

and inside the MainComponent's componentDidMount, I made the call

```
NativeModules.RCTDevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true);
```

I get the following error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'react_native_1.NativeModules.RCTDevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely')

What am I missing? I cannot use developer menu action sheet as I am inside an iMessage extension ( that does not support action sheet).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: `NativeModules.DevMenu.debugRemotely(true)`

Comment: Thanks.. But DevMenu is deprecated. Turns out Native.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true); is the correct call

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `NativeModules.DevMenu` has been removed in the latest RN releases. We must for only rely on `adb shell input keyevent 82` in case of android and `Ctrl + D` in case of iOS.